# Adding Oracle Database driver to ESB server

Tags: oracle, jdbc, esb, talend

I am new to ESB and have the Talend Runtime installed on my local machine and am able to run it partially. By partially I mean the child job of the ESB service does everything EXCEPT for performing an insert statement to an Oracle database. The error is the following:

```
Exception in component tOracleConnection_1
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver cannot be found
```

I'm a bit confused because prior to attempting to make the Oracle connection, it makes a connection, successfully, to a Greenplum database. So, my question is how do I point the ESB job, or the child job itself to the connection driver needed for Oracle?

I've found this link https://help.talend.com/reader/AskO0G1x~W7LBNnA0laezg/qEeVYD~sI3lhozl8PjJxRA and have attempted both the "bundle" method as well as the "installing simple copy to deploy folder" with no success.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the required jars in `[talend install directory]\esb\ContainerESB\lib\ext`

Comment: What if I don't have the `ContainerESB` directory?

Comment: It's possible that the name is different in your installation, it is configurable. I think the default is `container` but I'm not sure.

Comment: I got it working! You definitely pointed me in the right direction. I ended up just putting it in `<talend install directory>/esb/lib/` and it worked just fine!! Thank you.